# How to get start and end dates based on range provided in scala and also offset first day of week?

Tags: scala, date, time, jodatime

I am having following code for getting start dates for date range period provided

```
def dayIterator(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, period: String) = {
    period match {
      case "day"   => Iterator.iterate(start)(_ plusDays 1) takeWhile (_ isBefore end)
      case "week"  => Iterator.iterate(start)(_ plusWeeks 1) takeWhile (_ isBefore end)
      case "month" => Iterator.iterate(start)(_ plusMonths 1) takeWhile (_ isBefore end)
    }
  }
```

following code extracts the date based on period

```
 scala> dayIterator(new DateTime("2017-09-13"), new DateTime("2017-09-27"), "week").foreach(println)
    2017-09-13T00:00:00.000+05:30
    2017-09-20T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

I want start dates and end dates of week(or month) by offsetting first day of week as monday (or months' first day as 1st or start_date given)
so I expect output is like following (day name is mentioned for ref)

```
2017-09-13T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Wednesday) -- 2017-09-17T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Sunday)
2017-09-18T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Monday) -- 2017-09-24T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Sunday)
2017-09-25T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Monday) -- 2017-09-27T00:00:00.000+05:30 (Wednesday)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some trials and found following solution, I am converting final result dates to java.util.Date and putting it in a SortedMap

Following is the dayGroupGenerator function which takes care of offsetting

```
def dayGroupGenerator(startx: DateTime, endx: DateTime, period: String): scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Date, Date)] = {

    var start = startx
    var end = endx

    var dateSlots = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Date, Date)]()

    if (start.isAfter(end)) {
      dateSlots
    }
    else if (start.equals(end)) {
      dateSlots += ((start.toDate, end.toDate))
    }
    else {
      period match {
        case "day" => {
          while (start.equals(end) || start.isBefore(end)) {
            dateSlots += ((start.toDate, (if (start.equals(end) || start.isAfter(end)) end else start).toDate))
            start = start.plusDays(1)
          }
        }
        case "week" => {
          if (start.dayOfWeek.get != 1) {
            dateSlots += ((start.toDate, (if (start.withDayOfWeek(7).isAfter(end)) end else start.withDayOfWeek(7)).toDate))
            start = start.withDayOfWeek(7).plusDays(1)
          }

          while (start.equals(end) || start.isBefore(end)) {
            dateSlots += ((start.toDate, (if (start.equals(end) || start.withDayOfWeek(7).isAfter(end)) end else start.withDayOfWeek(7)).toDate))
            start = start.withDayOfWeek(7).plusDays(1)
          }
        }
        case "month" => {
          if (start.dayOfMonth.get != 1) {
            dateSlots += ((start.toDate, (if (start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue.isAfter(end)) end else start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue).toDate))
            start = start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue.plusDays(1)
          }

          while (start.equals(end) || start.isBefore(end)) {
            dateSlots += ((start.toDate, (if (start.equals(end) || start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue.isAfter(end)) end else start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue).toDate))
            start = start.dayOfMonth.withMaximumValue.plusDays(1)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    dateSlots
  }
```

You can paste above code in scala console as it is.
Call above function by using following scala console examples to see what I have tried to achieve

```
scala> import scala.collection.SortedMap
scala> import java.util.Date
scala> import org.joda.time.Days
scala> import org.joda.time.DateTime


scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-01-07"), new DateTime("2017-01-07"), "day").foreach(println)
scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-01-31"), new DateTime("2017-02-01"), "week").foreach(println)
scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-01-11"), new DateTime("2017-03-01"), "month").foreach(println)
scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-02-01"), new DateTime("2017-02-03"), "day").foreach(println)
scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-02-11"), new DateTime("2017-02-27"), "week").foreach(println)
scala> dayGroupGenerator(new DateTime("2017-03-13"), new DateTime("2017-05-30"), "month").foreach(println)
```

Note: I have not used DateTime in return type (Map[]) and used simpler java.util.Date because console was giving me following error for implicit Ordering of Joda DateTime

```
error: No implicit Ordering defined for org.joda.time.DateTime.
           var dateSlots = scala.collection.SortedMap[DateTime, DateTime]()
```